# Android ICS has a delay with detecting network loss. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: android, networking, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, connectivity, loss

When using Android with ICS there is a delay of about 3-4 seconds with BroadcastReceiver response.
Although I disconnect 3G and wifi a http request which happens right after occurs before BroadcastReceiver onReceive is called always, so the state of the network is not clear during the duration of 3-4 seconds.

1. Is this a known issue with ICS deviced?
2. Is there a better way to be aware asap of netwrok changes?

Thanks